# How can I source two paths for the ROS environmental variable at the same time?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, ros

I have a problem with using the rqt_image_view package in ROS. Each time when I type `rqt_image_view` or `rosrun rqt_image_view rqt_image_view` in terminal, it will return:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/rqt_image_view", line 16, in 
>       plugin_argument_provider=add_arguments))
>     File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 59, in main
>       return super(Main, self).main(argv, standalone=standalone, plugin_argument_provider=plugin_argument_provider, plugin_manager_settings_prefix=str(hash(os.environ['ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'])))
>     File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/main.py", line 338, in main
>       from python_qt_binding import QT_BINDING
>   ImportError: cannot import name QT_BINDING

In the /.bashrc file, I have source :

> source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
>   source /home/kelu/Dropbox/GET_Lab/leap_ws/devel/setup.bash --extend
>   source /eda/gazebo/setup.bash  --extend

They are the default path of ROS, my own working space, the robot simulator of our university. I must use all of them. I have already finished many projects with this environmental variable setting. However, when I want to use the package rqt_image_view today, it returns the above error info.

When I run `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, I get the return:

> /eda/gazebo/ros/kinetic/share:/home/kelu/Dropbox/GET_Lab/leap_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share

And `echo $PATH`

> /usr/local/cuda/bin:/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/home/kelu/bin:/home/kelu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Then I only source the  `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` ,the rqt_image_view package runs!!
It seems that, if I want to use rqt_image_view, then I can not source both `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` and `/home/kelu/Dropbox/GET_Lab/leap_ws/devel/setup.bash` at the same time.

Could someone tell me how to fix this problem? I have already search 5 hours in google and haven't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Different solutions to try:

- It sounds like the first path `/eda/gazebo/ros/kinetic/share` or `/home/kelu/Dropbox/GET_Lab/leap_ws/src` has an `rqt_image_view` package that is being used. Try to remove that dependency.
- Have you tried switching the source files being sourced? This depends on how the `rqt_image_view` package was built, such as by source or through a package manager.

Initially, it sounds like there is a problem with the paths being searched or wrong package being run since the package works with the default ROS environment setup.